# Out of memory with running JavaScript by PhantomJS

Tags: shell, phantomjs, out-of-memory

My shell script is written in **cygwin for windows**:

```
// main.sh
#!/bin/bash
[ "$#" -lt 1 ] && echo "Usage: thisscript.sh <filename.txt>" && exit 0
filename=`basename -s .txt $1`    
i=0
while [ $i == 0 ]
do
  phantomjs --web-security=no myXHR.js $filename.txt
  logLastLine=`tail -n 1 $filename.log`
  if [[ "$logLastLine" =~ "Error" ]]; then
    echo "Error occurs, now keep looping it..."
  elseif [[ "$logLastLine" =~ "503" ]]; then
    echo "Error occurs, now keep looping it..."
  elseif [[ "$logLastLine" =~ "500" ]]; then
    echo "Error occurs, now keep looping it..."
  else
    echo "Complete! Exiting the execution..."
    i=1
  fi
done
```

**And here are the codes contained in the `myXHR.js`**

```
// myXHR.js

phantom.onError = function(msg, trace) {
  console.log("PhantomJS Error");
  phantom.exit();
};


var fs = require('fs'), system = require('system');

if (system.args.length < 2) {
  console.log("Usage: myXHR.js <FILE>");
}

var content = '',
  f = null,
  lines = null,
  eol = "\n";

try {
  f = fs.open(system.args[1], "r");
  filename=system.args[1].replace(/\.txt/,"");
  content = f.read();
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}

if (f) {
  f.close();
}

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

if (content) {
  lines = content.split(eol);
  for (i=0; i<(lines.length-1);i++) {

  request.open('GET', "http://stackoverflow.com/", false);
  request.send();
  if （request.status === 200) {
    try { 
      fs.write($filename.log, line[i] + "Succeed!", 'a');
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  } else {  
    try { 
      fs.write($filename.log, line[i] + "Error!", 'a');
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
}
phantom.exit();
```

To illustrate, the **javascript, executed by PhantomJS**, are reading 1st argument(a `filename.txt` file), passed into the shell script, line by line. For each line it sends a XMLHttpRequest to check the request status and writes it into  `filename.log` file.

Error status number **includes 503 and 500**. Luckily these statuses are less likely to occur again if I resend the same XMLHttpRequest. So what I need to do is to set up a **error handler** which is for resend the same XMLHttpRequest when errors occur.

In this error handler, I use `X=${tail -n 1 log}` to see if there is a error status number(containing "503" or "500" string). For instance, `if [[ "$X" =~ "503" ]]; then` restart the execution of the javascript, by not giving `i=1` and while loop never exits. Until it has finished reading the last line of the imported file without any error status numbers.
(I know it is awkward to handle error like this, but it was a quick solution that came to my mind.)

But this is theoretical. In practice, this script ended with an error **"Memory exhausted"**. I reckon this error is triggered by the **large amount of lines(>100k) in the `$1` file**, and it occurs in the JavaScript execution part. I used `free -m` command to get memory usage information, and I noticed that when Javascript is running, the **used swap is increasing**!

Could anybody teach me how to release the memory when the scripts is  being executed.

Comment: There are no "clean memory commands" in shell programming, Cygwin or otherwise. One of the commands executed *by* the shell -- probably the one you didn't show, the one hidden behind the `#Here is a function` -- is using too much memory. You need to identify what that command is, why it uses too much memory, and fix the problem right there. Your error cannot be reproduced with the info you have given, making it impossible to give a "correct" answer to your question. Voting to close.

Comment: @DevSolar OK, I understand. I am wondering if I provided the function, the question will be complicated(including javascript executed by PhantomJS). But if it is required, I will provided it as much as possible. Sorry for not making the question clear.

Comment: Debugging 101: *isolate* a problem. Does it happen if you run *only* the Javascript part? That would be pretty significant, and require wholly different tags to the question. The Bash script would then be irrelevant. Or is it the `sed` that barfs on a certain line? *Which* line? That would be a `sed` question then, not a Bash question. And so forth.

Comment: Thanks @DevSolar, for keeping tracking this question. What you are just commenting is instructive. I think the `Memory exhausted` message is given out in the PhantomJS execution part, for it gives no other information before the `Memory exhausted` message, as PhantomJS should have.

Comment: I don't track it, when you write the "@" with a username that user gets always notified. And you're welcome, this is the thing about teaching a man to fish instead of just giving him a fish, if you know what I mean. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar That's what I appreciated most. :) I am now editing the question to make it better and clear.

Comment: Now, have a look at [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your question still does not make it possible to reproduce the problem... and while Javascript is definitely not my forte, the way you describe it... could it be that your error handler restarts the script over and over, without ever *finishing* one of the script runs? That would mean that, eventually, you have *thousands* of script instances running. No wonder you're running out of memory... (and it **still** hasn't anything to do with Cygwin, and "freeing memory in Cygwin" is a quite misleading title by now.

Comment: Try reading that file [one line at a time](http://phantomjs.org/api/stream/method/read-line.html) instead of all at once.

Comment: @pguardiario how to? use readLine() method provided by phantomjs?

Comment: It's documented in the link. It's just an idea.

Comment: @pguardiario This may serves a nice solution for my problem, I'll try it later. Perhaps, you could make it an answer, but not just a comment :-)